# Accordion is not working smoothly

Tags: codenameone

I've tried accordion and it doesn't expand and contract smoothly in both simulator and devices.Rather it expands and contract abruptly.

Please have a look at the video [here](https://youtu.be/MG47AahYPlM).

And how come there are 2 scroll bars.(At the end of the video you'll see 2 scrollbars, the inner one will scroll and outermost will stay static) There appears an extra black line on the rightmost screen.

```
public final class LabourCategory extends Form {

    public LabourCategory(Resources res) {
        super(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setTitle("Labour Category");

        loadComponent(res);
        revalidate();
    }

    public void loadComponent(Resources res) {
        Container mainContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        mainContainer.setUIID("small");
        mainContainer.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xcccccc);
        mainContainer.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
        mainContainer.getAllStyles().setMarginLeft(3);
        add(mainContainer);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Accordion labourCategory = new Accordion();
            labourCategory.addContent("Labour Category " + i,BoxLayout.encloseY(new Label("aaa"),new Label("bbb"), new Label("ccc")));
            labourCategory.setUIID("small");
            labourCategory.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
            labourCategory.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);

            mainContainer.add(labourCategory);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the jacky animation, change your form Layout to `BorderLayout` and add the `Accordion` to it directly or change `mainContainer` also to `BorderLayout`.

For the `Scrollbar`, you will have to manually remove it as `Accordion` is a subclass of `Container`.

Lastly, you don't need multiple `Accordion` for this purpose, just keep adding contents to one.

```
public final class LabourCategory extends Form {

    public LabourCategory(Resources res) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        setTitle("Labour Category");

        loadComponent(res);
        revalidate();
    }

    public void loadComponent(Resources res) {
        Accordion labourCategory = new Accordion();
        labourCategory.setUIID("small");
        labourCategory.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
        labourCategory.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
        labourCategory.setScrollVisible(false); //removes scrollbar

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            labourCategory.addContent("Labour Category " + i, BoxLayout.encloseY(new Label("aaa"), new Label("bbb"), new Label("ccc")));
        }

        Container mainContainer = BorderLayout.center(labourCategory);
        mainContainer.setUIID("small");
        mainContainer.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xcccccc);
        mainContainer.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
        mainContainer.getAllStyles().setMarginLeft(3);

        add(CENTER, mainContainer);    
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks Diamond. Then it needs borderlayout to work. And about multiple scrollbar, I am confused if it is of accordion. If the accordion is seen inside the device screen, then there is only one scroll but as soon as it exceeds the device height, then there are 2 scroll which is annoying. How can I remove the accordion scrollbar manually?

Comment: You could call `mainContainer.setScrollVisible(false);` and `getContentPane().setScrollVisible(false);` to hide Scrollbars on the wrapper container and the form.